# Using data from NSDictionary after being passed through segue

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I am trying to call data from a NSDictionary but am receiving an error.

This is the error that I am receiving:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSDictionary]' with an index of type 'String'
```

I am unsure of the right method to take to retrieve the key from the NSDictionary after passing it through a segue. I am using JSONSerialization to set the api json to the dictionary. The question is when I am not using a tableview or collection view indexpath how do I retrieve data from the NSDictionary?

Here is the example shown in Apple's documentation:

`let value = dictionary["helloString"]`

Here is my prepareForSegue Code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailsSegue" {
        if let details = segue.destination as? DetailsView {
            if let film = sender as? [NSDictionary]? {
                details.films = film
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my DetailsView Code:

```
import UIKit
import AFNetworking

class DetailsView: UIViewController {

let homepage = FilmsViewController()    

var films: [NSDictionary]?
var videos: [NSDictionary]?

@IBOutlet var detailsImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var detailsTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var releaseDate: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var overview: UILabel!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    detailsTitle.text = films?["title"] as? NSString

    loadFilms()

}
}
```

I've also tried it as:

`detailsTitle.text = films?["results]["title"] as? NSString`

In a CollectionView on another ViewController it worked as:

`film = films?[indexPath.row]
 title = film?["title"]`

The NSDictionary is being parsed through this code and AFNetworking:

```
////////Parse Film API//////////////////

func loadFilms() {

    let apiKey = "97a0d64910120cbeae9df9cb675ad235"
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=\(apiKey)&language=en-US&page=1")
    let request = URLRequest(
        url: url! as URL,
        cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
        timeoutInterval: 10 )

    let session = URLSession (
        configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
        delegate: nil,
        delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main
    )

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (dataOrNil, response, error) in
        if let data = dataOrNil {
            if let resposeDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? NSDictionary {

                self.films = resposeDictionary["results"] as? [NSDictionary]
                print("response: \(resposeDictionary)")
            }

        }

    })


    task.resume()

}

//////////End Parse Film API///////////////////
```

Here is the JSON. I am trying to access the key:

```
{
"id": 335983,
"results": [
{
  "id": "5a7c6a35c3a3680f7f01053a",
  "iso_639_1": "en",
  "iso_3166_1": "US",
  "key": "dzxFdtWmjto",
  "name": "VENOM - Official Teaser Trailer (HD)",
  "site": "YouTube",
  "size": 1080,
  "type": "Teaser"
},
{
  "id": "5a7cd5389251414b22019912",
  "iso_639_1": "en",
  "iso_3166_1": "US",
  "key": "MDR3bfmzV8c",
  "name": "VENOM - Teaser Trailer - In Cinemas October 4",
  "site": "YouTube",
  "size": 1080,
  "type": "Teaser"
},
```

Comment: Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use a proper Swift dictionary and make things much simpler.

Comment: The error tells you the answer! Just read what it says. You do not have a dictionary. You have an _array_ of dictionaries.

Comment: so error is about you are accessing the array object with string, in above type [NSDictionary] you have to access it with int for example `let movieId = videos![0]`. Looking at your example you are trying to access the video on button click, so use some tag to play button and use that tag to identify the video. example code```@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let video = videos![sender.tag] , movieId = video["key"]
    let video = AVPlayer(url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(movieId)")
    }```

Comment: Well. You didn't pay attention. Tell me, __how do you access the `n`th element of an `Array`?__ and __how do you access the `n`th element of a `Dictionary`?__. ___Accessing `n`th element of a `Dictionary` doesn't make sense because it's an unordered collection___. So first get some knowledge of accessing elements from `Array` & `Dictionary`. Forget about the **JSON** for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final answer to this was to convert everything from NSDictionary to the swift 4 Codable data structure

Answer (score 0):

Because videos is an array of dictionaries. Firstly you have to parse array with for or foreach loop, then you can access key-value pair. And instead of using NSDictionary, try to use Dictionary or [String:Any] usage. Example is below

```
var videos: [Dictionary<String,Any>] = [
["key":"val1"],
["key":"val2"],
["key":"val3"]
]

videos.forEach { (dict) in
print(dict["key"] ?? "")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have array of video dictionary. You want to access the video on play button click. To do so with your existing code it is possible with some changes.

Assumptions you must be using some list UI component which render the video list. in each list item you have play button. you need to give tag to play button, it can be index of the list for that item, if you are using TableView you can use indepath.row as the tag to button.

After that you need to make following changes in your play button action

```
@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let video = videos![sender.tag] 
    let movieId = video["key"]
    let video = AVPlayer(url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(movieId)"
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
    videoPlayer.player = video

    present(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
        video.play()
    })
}
```

I tried to explain same thing in comment as well.

Comment: What would the sender.tag be if it's been sent through a segue?